# Print a word with space after each character that was inserted in an input using python

Tags: python

I would like to print the result of a text or word that is digited at a input with space between every character/letter/number, how can i do it with python?

I did some searchs, but i only found the code for 2 or more characters...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you looking for `' '.join(s)`?

Comment: yes, like this John, but i would like to put the space after every character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John said in the comments, you can use `str.join` for this:

```
>>> x = input()
Hello
>>> ' '.join(x)
'H e l l o'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to split text like this: `'lorem ipsum'` to `['lorem','ipsum']`, you could use `x = string.split()`.